# Putting Labels at the center or inside a polygon layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-1

How can I put labels at the center or at least inside a polygon layer using QGIS Lisboa (old version). I tried options provided on Layer Properties under placements but still my label just falls outside desired layer.

Comment: It will be difficult to get answers for Lisboa, since most people don't have these old versions installed anymore. Why not update?